# Unable to insert new element between 2 elements having the same parent

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert `<hr>` between first and second `.field-container`. Both share the same parent so, `element1.parentNode.insertBefore(element2, ...)` should work. It's not working and I'm getting an error instead.

```js
(function() {
    let containers = document.querySelectorAll('.field-container');
    let hr = document.createElement('hr');
    containers[0].parentNode.insertBefore(containers[1], hr);
})();
```

```html
 

<div>
    <div class="field-container">
        <input placeholder="Field 1" type="text">
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="field-container">
        <input placeholder="Field 2" type="text">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

By appending `hr` first to the parent element then trying to insert it between both containers fixes the error but the insertion happens at the end, not between.

```js
(function() {
    let containers = document.querySelectorAll('.field-container');
    let hr = document.createElement('hr');
    containers[0].parentNode.appendChild(hr);
    containers[0].parentNode.insertBefore(containers[1], hr);
})();
```

```html
 

<div>
    <div class="field-container">
        <input placeholder="Field 1" type="text">
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="field-container">
        <input placeholder="Field 2" type="text">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `containers[0].parentNode.insertBefore(hr, containers[1]);`

Comment: @cmgchess This works. I don't understand why it works though. Isn't the first argument of `insertBefore` supposed to already exist in the parent node?

Comment: @YuvarajM I have 2 groups of fields which I need to separate using some sort of separator. Is there something wrong with choosing to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)
Since you need the `hr` before `containers[1]`
your `newNode`  or node to be inserted is the `hr` and the `referenceNode` or node before which newNode is inserted is the `containers[1]`

```js
(function() {
    let containers = document.querySelectorAll('.field-container');
    let hr = document.createElement('hr');
    // containers[0].parentNode.appendChild(hr); this not needed
    containers[0].parentNode.insertBefore(hr, containers[1]);
})();
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="field-container">
        <input placeholder="Field 1" type="text">
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="field-container">
        <input placeholder="Field 2" type="text">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Comments**

1. The problem is that this code backwards. Instead of `insertBefore(containers[1], hr)` do this `insertBefore(hr, containers[1])`
2. Another problem is that you are moving a single <hr> instead of inserting two <hr> elements
3. Below is a cleaner example

**JS**

```js
(function() {
    const [ firstChild, secondChild ] = document.querySelectorAll('.field-container');
    const parent = firstChild.parentElement;
    parent.appendChild( document.createElement('hr') )
    parent.insertBefore( document.createElement('hr'), secondChild );
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

> You does not need any complex js for this, just use CSS

```css
:root{
  --margin:15px;
}
.field-container{
  margin:var(--margin);
  position:relative;
  width:min-content;
}

.field-container:not(:last-child)::after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom: calc(var(--margin)* -1 / 2);
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  border-bottom:2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
    <div class="field-container">
        <input placeholder="Field 1" type="text">
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="field-container">
        <input placeholder="Field 2" type="text">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```